# .Net Core Integration TestServer with Generic IHostBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit, asp.net-core-3.0

I've updated my website with **.Net Core 3.0 preview 2** and I want to make **Integration Test** with a TestServer. In .Net Core 2.2, I've been able to make it using `WebApplicationFactory<Startup>`

Since `WebHostBuilder` is about to be deprecated (see (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) for more details.), I want to follow up and implement the new Generic `HostBuilder` now. It is working great for launching the website but it crashes when I launch my **Integration tests**. I know that `WebApplicationFactory` does use `WebHostBuilder` and that's why it's crashing, but I don't know how to change it for the Generic `HostBuilder`.

Here is my code that was working in .Net Core 2.2 :

```
namespace CompX.FunctionalTest.Web.Factory
{
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Create a new service provider.
                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                // Add a database context (ApplicationDbContext) using an in-memory 
                // database for testing.
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
                });

                services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Identity");
                    options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
                });

                services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>()
                        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

                // Build the service provider.
                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                // Create a scope to obtain a reference to the database
                // context (ApplicationDbContext).
                using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                    var loggerFactory = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

                    var logger = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

                    // Ensure the database is created.
                    db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                    try
                    {
                        // Seed the database with test data.
                        var userManager = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                        AppIdentityDbContextSeed.SeedAsync(userManager).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        logger.LogError(ex, $"An error occurred seeding the database with test messages. Error: {ex.Message}");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I tried with `TestServers` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`, but it needs `new WebHostBuilder()` as parameters.

I also tried to pass this as parameters, but it didn't work as well :

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

It can't find the `.ConfigureWebHostDefaults()`function.

Did anyone successfuly implemented a Test server in .Net Core 3.0 ?
Thanks a lot !

PS : I'm kinda new to .Net Core

**EDIT :**

That's the error that I get from all the methods that try to make a new server :
[image]

Here is the `program.cs`

```
namespace CompX.Web
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

**Here is the issue that I've created on github :**
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7754

Comment: Can you show your Program.cs file?

Comment: Sure, i'll add it in the edit.

Comment: The test factory is waiting for an iwebhostbuilder but you use an ihostbuilder instead. I'm not sure this is currently supported. As there are lot of changes happening on theses API. Need to check aspnet source code ...

Comment: Ok thanks, If I don't get an answer from Stack, I might go ask directly on the aspnet core github if they added this feature.

Comment: I quickly checked the source code and everything use the iwebhostbuilder version. https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Hosting/TestHost/src/WebHostBuilderExtensions.cs

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll open an issue on the 3.0 branch and ask them if they can add this feature for the Generic HostBuilder. I'll mark my question as "answered" when they'll make it or if someone comes up with an idea :).

Thanks a lot Kalten !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got how to do it in 3.0.
Here's the full walkthrough on how to do it for anyone that needs the solution :

1. You need to have atleast **.Net Core 3.0.0-preview2**, since they added the `WebApplicationFactory` with `IHostbuilder` in this preview (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/6585). You can find it here : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0
2. Upgrade atleast theses packages to version 3.0.0 (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3756 and https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3755):

   - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App Version=3.0.0-preview-19075-0444`
   - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing Version= 3.0.0-preview-19075-0444`
   - `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting Version=3.0.0-preview.19074.2`
3. Remove now deprecated packages that are now included in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`:

   - `Microsoft.AspNetCore Version=2.2.0`
   - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy Version=2.2.0`
   - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy Version=2.2.0`
   - `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity Version=2.2.0`
4. If your were using `services.AddIdentity` in your `WebApplicationFactory<Startup>` builder, you'll need to delete it. Otherwise, you'll have a new error saying that you have **already use that scheme** for `Identity.Application`. It looks like the new `WebApplicationFactory` is using the one from `Startup.cs` now.

I had nothing else to modify.
Hope it will be helpful for some people !

**Update :**

It was working well until I had to use another Integration C# file (e.g `LoginTest.cs` and `ManageTest.cs`). The problem was that when I ran my test, it would infinitly loop until I pressed CTRL + C.
After that, it would display an **Access Denied** error.

Once again, I had to remove something from my `WebApplicationFactory`, the seeds :

```
            try
            {
                // Seed the database with test data.
                var userManager = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                AppIdentityDbContextSeed.SeedAsync(userManager).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, $"An error occurred seeding the database with test messages. Error: {ex.Message}");
            }
```

It looks like the new `WebApplicationFactory` was trying to recreate the usermanager for each factories. I replaced my seeded user accounts with Guid.NewGuid().

Took me a while to figure it out. Hope it might help someone, once again.

Comment: Where can you find Microsoft.AspNetCore.App version 3? I can only find Microsoft.AspNetCore.App verison 2.2.7. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/

Comment: I guess you mean that also Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 should be removed?

Comment: Hi, Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is now obsolete. It wasn't when I was working with the preview 2. It's now a part of the .Net Core SDK 3.0 

Here's the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio 

under the section "Remove obsolete package reference". You only need to delete the reference unless your project SDK is Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference).